# i need to insert <br /> in reactjs with condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, variables

my code is used to create cards with 4 card in a line so I used this code but it just outputs the 
 as it is.it uses map function to take values from another file dataCard

```
const moduleCards = dataCard.map(modules => {
  let idValue = (modules.id%4===0)&& '<br />'
   return(
     <div>
   <Modules 
     name={modules.name} 
     subject={modules.subject} 
   />
   {idValue}

   </div>
   )   
  } 
  )
```

Comment: This should work (modules.id%4===0) && <br /> without ''

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @lissettdm, this line

```
let idValue = (modules.id%4===0)&& '<br />'
```

should be changed to this:

```
let idValue = modules.id % 4 === 0 && <br />
```